# Clarification on WSO2 Developer Studio

Tags: intellij-idea, eclipse-plugin, wso2, wso2-integration-studio

I have used WSO2 Developer Studio. I have found that this tooling is in the Eclipse IDE environment. My first question , Is this a plugin of Eclipse? or separate tooling? Second question, Is there any distribution of WSO2 Developer Studio with intelliJIDEA environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WSo2 studio](https://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/) is a standalone Eclipse-based product.

WS02 also provide the same features in the form of [Eclipse plugins](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/wso2-developer-studio).

So, the tool you are using can be both "a plugin of Eclipse" and "separate tooling".

However, there is no IntelliJ flavour of WSO2 Studio and there are no IntelliJ plugins (have a look at the [IntelliJ Plugin Repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?correctionAllowed=true&pr=&orderBy=&search=wso2)) equivalent to the WSO2 Eclipse plugins.